# Calculating Percentiles on a vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, statistics

I have a vector layer in QGIS with various numeric fields and I would like to calculate the percentiles, 90-95-99, for each of the fields. I have tried the GRASS v.univariate algorithm but this only does one percentile at a time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you want these percentiles? If you sort on a feature, then the 90th percentile value will be the value of the attribute for the feature at row 0.9 times the number of features. You could simply read that off - I'm not sure how to get a whole set of attribute values into an array to do it in an expression. Otherwise you might need a python function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pyqgis with [numpy.percentile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

```
import numpy as np

#Change these two lines to match your data:
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_my_riks')[0]
fieldname = 'area'

data =[f[fieldname] for f in lyr.getFeatures()] #List all values in column

for p in [90, 95, 99]:
    print("{0} th percentile is: {1}".format(p, np.percentile(data, p)))
```

[image]