# Running vector percentile breaks is very slow QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, vector, style, numpy

I solved my own question a couple weeks ago on how to create percentile breaks in QGIS.

[Creating percentile class breaks in vector data QGIS using numpy.percentile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416164/creating-percentile-class-breaks-in-vector-data-qgis-using-numpy-percentile)

However, this code is unbelievably slow. Does anyone have any recommendations for speeding things up? See code below:

```
case
    when ag_ppm <= q1(ag_ppm)
        then '<25th: ' || minimum("ag_ppm") || ' - ' || q1(ag_ppm)
    when ag_ppm < median(ag_ppm) AND ag_ppm > q1(ag_ppm)
        then '25th to 50th: ' || (q1(ag_ppm)+0.001) || ' - ' || median(ag_ppm)
    when ag_ppm <= q3(ag_ppm) AND ag_ppm > median(ag_ppm)
        then '50th to 75th: ' || (median(ag_ppm)+0.001) || ' - ' || q3(ag_ppm)
    when ag_ppm <= percentile(90,array_agg(ag_ppm,project)) AND ag_ppm > q3(ag_ppm)
        then '75th to 90th: ' || (q3(ag_ppm)+0.001) || ' - ' || percentile(90,array_agg(ag_ppm,project))
    when ag_ppm <= percentile(95,array_agg(ag_ppm,project)) AND ag_ppm > percentile(90,ag_ppm)
        then '90th to 95th: ' || (percentile(90,array_agg(ag_ppm,project))+0.001) || ' - ' || percentile(95,array_agg(ag_ppm,project))
    when ag_ppm <= percentile(98,ag_ppm) AND ag_ppm > percentile(95,ag_ppm)
        then '95th to 98th: ' || (percentile(95,array_agg(ag_ppm,project))+0.001) || ' - ' || percentile(98,array_agg(ag_ppm,project))
    when ag_ppm <= maximum(ag_ppm) AND ag_ppm > percentile(98,array_agg(ag_ppm,project))
        then '>98th: ' || (percentile(98,array_agg(ag_ppm,project))+0.001) || ' - ' || maximum(ag_ppm)
    else 'NULL'
end
```

Comment: You can change the `case when` to several `if` statements, then you compute and store the variables that are reused (ex: start by computing `valq1 = q1(ag_ppm)` and then use `valq1` in the comparisons). It should cut the processing time in half at least. Then you can reorder the comparisons, moving away from the median (most likely bin if you have a normal distribution) to avoid computing/comparing stats of outliers first

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a try. Although it seems that even a single if statement with percentile takes forever with 1000+ records. I'm wondering if the numpy percentile function is a bit chuggy

Comment: UPDATE: but even a single if statement takes 5+ minutes to classify. eg. if(ag_ppm <= percentile(90,array_agg(ag_ppm)),'<25th: ' ,NULL)

Comment: As it is, you are computing the classification and the percentiles for every feature, so more than 1000 times. Try using the graduated symbology, or the rule based symbology, and modify your python function so you call it once only and it populates the class breaks. Once the breaks have been defined, the classification is done comparing `ag_ppm` to static values only so it will be much faster

Comment: I have tried using rule-based which is just as slow. I didn't think you could use a formula for breaks in graduated symbols. I have no idea how to do this if it's possible